# Why don't the cscope show index and line number on the vim?

Tags: vim, cscope

My OS version is MAC OS X 10.10,  installed with vim(7.3) and cscope(15.8a).
But it can't show index and line number properly:
[the screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ4yi.jpg)

The configuration about the cscope in the ~/.vimrc is as follows:

```
if has("cscope")
      set csprg=/usr/local/bin/cscope
      set csto=1
      set cst 
      set nocsverb
      " add any database in current directory
      if filereadable("cscope.out")
          cs add cscope.out
      endif
          set csverb
endif
```

I don't know where the problem is, please give me some tips, thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you press `1`?

Comment: Maybe it's a color scheme problem? Try setting a different one.

Comment: It's should be related to the built-in terminal, it works after I switched to another.